# SET statement considers 0 as null

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I don't how to explain my problem but I will try my best to be clear.

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will be used to handle holidays requests. I have two tables:

Table A contains the name of the holiday and the max number of days that can be requested in a year. It goes like this

```
TABLE A
------------------------
| HOLIDAY NAME| QUOTA  |
------------------------
| Yearly      | 40     |
------------------------
```

Table B tracks all the holidays requests and automatically updates the remaining number of days for a specific holiday. After multiple requests, the column 'Balance' determines how many days are still available. In the case below, the balance is 0 after the last request.

```
TABLE B
----------------------------------------------------
| HOLIDAY NAME | FROM       | TO         | BALANCE |
----------------------------------------------------
| Yearly       | 2019-10-12 | 2019-10-22 | 0       |
----------------------------------------------------
```

What I want is that, whenever the balance is 0, a request for a new holiday should not get through. To achieve this, I have applied the following logic (an extract of my procedure):

```
DECLARE @quota_requested int, @quota int, @balance int, @balance_new int, @period_from date, @period_to date
SET     @period_from = '2019-12-27'
SET     @period_to = '2019-12-31'
SET @quota_requested = (datediff(dd, @period_from, @period_to) + 1) - (datediff(wk, @period_from, @period_to)*2) - (CASE WHEN datename(dw,@period_from) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - (CASE WHEN datename(dw, @period_to) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
SET @balance = (SELECT balance FROM dbo.TABLE_B WHERE holiday = 'Yearly')
SET @quota = (SELECT quota FROM dbo.TABLE_A WHERE holiday = 'Yearly')

IF @balance is null
    SET @balance_new = @quota 
ELSE 
    SET @balance_new = @balance
```

What I do in this code is:

- I compute the number of days that a person requests (@quota_requested)
- I compare it with the quota that is allowed for that holiday (@quota)

  ```
  * If @quota_requested > @quota: Don't proceed
  * If @quota_requested <= @quota: Proceed to next check
  ```
- I compare the number of days requested with the balance for that holiday (@balance)

  ```
  * If @quota_requested > @balance: Don't proceed
  * If @quota_requested <= @balance: Insert the request into the table
  ```

This logic works very well whenever the balance > 0 but when the balance gets to 0, the following part of the code:

```
SET @balance = (SELECT balance FROM dbo.TABLE_B WHERE holiday = 'Yearly')
```

passes `NULL` to the variable `@balance` even though the balance = 0. As a result, I am never able to stop the insert when the balance gets to zero and the code starts the balance to the value of the quota due to this part of the code:

```
IF @balance = null or @balance = '' or @balance is null
    SET @balance_new = @quota 
ELSE 
    SET @balance_new = @balance
```

I would really like to know what is going on here and why 0 is being treated as `NULL`. May this be due to the `SET` function? I changed to `SELECT` but this didn't change a thing.

Thank you

Comment: `@balance = NULL` is never going to work; nothing is "equal" to `NULL` as its value is unknown. You have to use `IS (NOT) NULL` for comparisons.

Comment: That's why I have added ```@balance is null```. Actually the part where I write  ```@balance = null``` should be taken out.

Comment: Also, I can't [replicate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ecdf2b1764757fdd3ae949d6fbebd030) your problem. Something else is going on here that we have been told about.

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are two different rdbms products with different implementations of sql. The code in the question is for ms sql server, not for mysql. Pls pay attention to use appropriate tags, otherwise the question may mislead the answerers.

Comment: @Shadow I have removed the MySql tag. Thank You!

Comment: @Larnu the balance comes out as 0 in your link. That's the expectation

Comment: Is it, perhaps because you think that `'' = 0` would return false? You'd be wrong if so. Have you actually checked the value of `@Balance` before that `IF`?

Comment: Yes, I have printed each one of the parameter ```SELECT @balance, @balance_new, @quota_requested```. Everytime, the value of ```@balance``` is 0 but after the ```SET``` it becomes ```NULL```

Comment: If it *really* does have a value of `NULL` please provide a fiddle to replicate it; what you have given us doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal ball answer

The problem is you think that `0` and `''` are different values; with numerical data types you would be wrong. Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 0 WHEN '' THEN 0 END;
```

You get the result 0 right? That's because `''` was converted the to an `int` and as an `int` the value is `0`.

That's why your `IF` results in true. I'm not honestly sure why you're comparing an `int` to a `varchar` though.

Comment: The thing is the first line of the ```IF``` statement shouldn't be true if ```@balance = 0```. I have decided to use a work-around by splitting my ```IF``` statement like this: ```if @balance is null set @balance_new = @quota if @balance >= 0 set @balance_new = @balance```. This seems to work. But I still can't understand why the first line is coming out as true, however

Comment: Because `''` and `0` have the **same** value @BrunoBukavuThai , because you're dealing with integers, not strings. I

Comment: Indeed. I tried again but this time by removing the condition ```@balance = ''``` and the whole thing worked. I really didn't think that ```''``` and ```0```would be the same thing. Thanks @Larnu